# Consumir un servicios REST Ajax para un ComboBox

Tags: ajax

actualamente quiero consumir 2 servicios rest uno que lista departamentos de una url de manera local, aca la lista de departamentos :http://localhost:3000/departamentos

```html
[{"iIdSede":3,"iIdSedeZona":1,"vcDescripcion":"PASCO"},{"iIdSede":5,"iIdSedeZona":11,"vcDescripcion":"LIMA"},{"iIdSede":85,"iIdSedeZona":5,"vcDescripcion":"AREQUIPA"},{"iIdSede":86,"iIdSedeZona":7,"vcDescripcion":"PISCO"},
```

Y el otro que cuando selecciono un departamento me seleccione sus provincia por el id del departamento seleccionado un ejemplo , donde el id = 3 :http://localhost:3000/departamentos/provincia/3

```html
[{"vcDescripcion":"Cerro de Paso"},{"vcDescripcion":"Oxapampa"},{"vcDescripcion":"Daniel Carrion"}
```

Lo quiero hacer es consumirlo con Ajax para los dos ComboBox pero no se como hacerlo si me podrian ayudar, se le agradeceria mucho

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Departamentos y su Provincias";
}
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        Departamentos y su Provincias
    </h1>

</section>
<br />
<label class="col-md-6">ORIGEN</label>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-6">Sede</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select id="depaId" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Select">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-6">Servicio</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select id="proviId" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Select">Seleccione</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Osea lo quiero es consumir esos servicios por ajax para los combobox

Comment: Alguien que me ayude porfa

Comment: Edita la pregunta, y enseñanos lo que estas intentando

Comment: Osea lo que quiero hacer es llenar un select desde Ajax